# Best practice - Distinguish between environments (PHP)

Tags: php

I need to make some slight configuration changes in my local dev env.
Thus, I would like to know what is the "best practice" in distinguishing between environments.
I would like to have only one config file which will behave differently depending on which environment it is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common and good practice is to use different `.env` files on different environments.

> Basically, a `.env` file is an easy way to load custom configuration
>   variables that your application needs without having to modify
>   .htaccess files or Apache/Nginx virtual hosts. This means you won't
>   have to edit any files outside the project, and all the environment
>   variables are always set no matter how you run your project - Apache,
>   Nginx, CLI, and even PHP 5.4's built-in webserver. It's WAY easier
>   than all the other ways you know of to set environment variables, and
>   you're going to love it.

You can use some already created packages to add this to your project. Check this one: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

**Example (just for a demo, not production ready code!):**

*Note! You will need to add `.env` to `.gitignore` file to keep it not synced between environments.*

Development `.env` file:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Production `.env` file:

```
DB_HOST=192.168.10.1
DB_USER=dbUser
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Possible `config.php` file:

```
<?php

// add composer autoload somewhere here...

$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

return [
    'db' => [
        'host' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'user' => getenv('DB_USER'),
        'pass' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    ]
]
```